# Map not displaying when accessed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web

I have this HTML file(below) Which is almost identical to the one found here. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

My issue I'm am having is I see nothing wrong with any of the script portion or HTML, then again I'm writing this for a non-profit as a volunteer and I don't normally do this HTML or javascript. This file is generated by a perl script so please be easy on me.

Let me know what i did wrong please!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>e-NABLE Event Map</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>

    function initialize() {
        var myHome = new google.maps.Latlng(-77.675106,43.090076);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myHome
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementByID('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
          '</div>'+
          '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
          '<div id="bodyContent">'+
          '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
          'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
          'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
          'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
          '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
          'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
          'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
          'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
          'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
          'Heritage Site.</p>'+
          '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
          'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
          '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
          '</div>'+
          '</div>';

        var myLatlng0 = new google.maps.LatLng(-77.675106,43.090076);

        var infowindow0 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng0,
            map: map,
            title: 'e-NABLE Home Base'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker0, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker0);
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I suggest you try @PHPGlue's code and mark the answer as accepted. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. `new google.maps.Latlng(-77.675106,43.090076)` is supposed to be `new google.maps.LatLng(-77.675106,43.090076)` and`document.getElementByID('map-canvas')` should be `document.getElementById('map-canvas')`. Personally, I don't like to type `google.maps` or use `document.getElementById()`, so I do this:

```
var doc = document, bod = document.body, gm = google.maps;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
var myHome = new gm.LatLng(-77.675106,43.090076);
var canvas = E('map-canvas'); // same as document.getElementById('map-canvas');
```

Comment: Great catches, however it is still not working for me. I'm looking at the html file and I see no syntax errors, but still no map :(

Comment: NVM, got it working however my infowindows are not showing. off to fix that issue!